# How to Update a group of rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

My sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4f9da/1

I'm really bad explaining this and noob to do complex query(just the basics), because its complicated.

Situation: The column revision is a group of the same object related, for example: ids `1 2 3` are the same object and always refering the last old object on using `id` to `ground_id`.

Problem: I need to make `ord` column to make same id for the same group of object. example: the ids `1 2 3` need their value setted to `1`, because the revison `0` is the id `1`. Same for id `4`, which must have ord `4` and id `5` too.

Basically must be like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a [recursive query](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING) to do this. First you select the rows where `ground_id IS NULL`, set `ord` to the value of `id`. In the following iterations you add more rows based on the value of `ground_id`, setting the `ord` value to that of the row it is being matched to. You can then use that set of rows `(id, ord)` as a row source for the `UPDATE`:

```
WITH RECURSIVE set_ord (id, ord) AS (
  SELECT id, id 
  FROM ground 
  WHERE ground_id IS NULL
  UNION
  SELECT g.id, o.ord
  FROM ground g 
  JOIN set_ord o ON o.id = g.ground_id
)
UPDATE ground g
  SET ord = s.ord
  FROM set_ord s
  WHERE g.id = s.id;
```

(SQLFiddle is currently not-responsive so I can't post my code there)

Comment: Do you know what it changes from postgres 8? On 9 works fine, but on 8 gives me error from the syntax UPDATE. I saw on docs and theres no difference.

Comment: The recursive query with `UPDATE` is only available since version 9.1. But you really shouldn't be using such an old version anymore; 8.4 was at end of support by July 2014. The [8.4 docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-update.html) do not show the option with the recursive query.

Comment: I know, In my dev it is 9.4 but when I checked on production, it is 8.14.4. Going migrate it.